# Blade not working (Laravel), why is nothing shown?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Blade not working (Laravel), why is nothing shown?

1.show.blade.php

```
@extends('book.show')
@section('comment')
    Yuup!
@endsection
```

2.book/show.blade.php

```
<ul class="cols">
    <li>
       @yield('comment')
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try add some HTML content (e.g. `<p>Paragraph</>`) to `show.blade.php` and check if this content is shown.

Comment: Please show us the controller (may be something in there causing an exception), also if you have correct permissions for /storage set to 777?

Comment: @Ján Kyselica, nothing

Comment: @Dan White. add code (pastebin) [link](http://pastebin.com/tYuRLcMB)

Comment: Im not really sure what you want to do with yielding comments, but if you want to load comments inside a view, I recommend you to use a partial for this. See [this laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/13) for further information and instruction.

Comment: @JustDevelop, tnx :(

Comment: Check if php settings for error_reporting is set to 1, and try to set 777 to /storage folder, as @Dan White tell. And try to set some sample html to every blade template to check where issue is.

Comment: You should probably post your routes file while you're at it.

Comment: @user3648218 Yep. Looks like your problem was your routes. Check my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing was wrong with the displayed code. The problem was in your routes. Here is a snippet from your routes:

```
Route::get('book/{book}', function () {
    $comment = 'Hello';
    return view('comment.show', ['comment' => $comment]);
});

Route::resource('book', 'BookController');
```

`Route::resource('book')` creates the exact same URI as `'book/{book}'` so it overrides the first one. In other words, your closure is never triggered. You have several options.

1. Don't use `Route::resource`. I like to be explicit with my routes.
2. Put your `Route::get('book/{book}` after the `Route::resource`. This would work too.
3. Remove `Route::get('book/{book}')` and just add your code inside your `BookController` classes `show` method.

Any of these 3 options will work. I suggest option #3 if you like using `Route::resource`. Otherwise, I would work with option #1. Option #2 and overriding other routes and such isn't a very nice way of going about things in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code in pastebin.

Change `return view('comment.show', ['comment' => $comment]);` to `return view('book.show', ['comment' => $comment]);`

**EDIT**

Another problem is you end your section with `@endsection`. It will be `@stop`.

Your code should look like this:

```
@extends('book.show')
@section('comment')
    Yuup!
@stop
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96528/discussion-on-answer-by-smartrahat-blade-not-working-laravel-why-is-nothing-s).